# How to change the text of a subscript in an equation tool of Word with VBA (OMaths object)?

Tags: vba, ms-word, equation, subscript

I tried the following code which is working well for text in the equation:

```
For Each eqns In ActiveDocument.OMaths
    With eqns.Range.Find
        .Text = "pSmt"
        .Replacement.Text = "Text"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
Next
```

BUT, the following code to change the subscript was without success: no error, but no change, with the IF condition or without.

```
For Each eqns In ActiveDocument.OMaths
    If eqns.Range.Font.Subscript = True Then
        With eqns.Range.Find
            '.Font.Subscript = True
            .Text = "aSmt"
            .Replacement.Text = "Sub"
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    End If
Next
```

I also tried to use the underscore part of the String, but I am no sure what I am doing.
I couldn't find something I can understand online, then if you have an idea, please let me know.

Comment: As far as I can tell, .Find only finds text in Equations that has been marked as plain text within the equation (e.g. you selected it and clicked the Text button in the Equation toolbar, or you surrounded it by single straight quotation characters. If 'pSmt' has been marked that way, Word may find it. If 'aSmt' has not been marked that way, Word will not find it. Also, if 'aSmt' *is* marked that way and is in a Subscript, Word does not actually "see" the text as having .Subscript format, i.e. adding .Font.Subscript = True will cause the .Find.Execute to fail.

Comment: (single straight quotation characters should be double straight quotation characters)

Comment: I think I am making progress, but not there yet. I tried `.ClearFormatting` and `.Format = True` without the Subscript line and it is working partially. If aSmt is subscript and not bold, it is working. I get the result I want. But, unfortunately, my subscript aSmt is in Bold and it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: To me, what to do next would depend very much on whether the problem is a one-off (e.g. it is really just finding pSmt with this formatting here and sSmt with that formatting there) or much more general, and what the extent of the problem is (one big document, 100 small documents, something you do one time, something you have to do once a day, etc.) Personally, I would already be looking away from using FInd/Replace and thinking about using VBA or whatever to iterate through the OMath objects or perhaps looking inside the .docx/.zip at the document.xml file. No easy solution I suspect!

Answer (score 0):

`If eqns.Range.Font.Subscript = True Then` will only evaluate to true if the entire equation is in subscript.

For `Find.Font.Subscript` to work you need to inlude `Find.Format = True` otherwise the Find function won’t know that it’s looking for formatting.

Comment: OK, I get rid off the If-EndIf condition and add `.Format = true`, `.Font.Subscript = True` in the code above, I still have no change. I also tried to add a `.ClearFormatting` as the first line in the With loop without success.